# Gradle Version Upgrade Triggers an Unable To find Method Error

Tags: gradle

I upgraded Gradle version from 3.5.2 to 4.0.2. But I am getting unable to find method error. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

[See My Terminal:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQfSy.jpg)

Comment: "Stopping all gradle daemons can help solve this problem"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see the screenshot